# How to set a maximum and minimum value for a WKInterfaceSlider programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit

I know it is possible to set values through Attribute Inspector. However, the range of the slider needs to change according to the data that comes from the server. In this case, hard coding the values isn't an option. Is there any way to set it programmatically?

Comment: can you provide response of the server? and in which condition or when you want to change slider value.?

Comment: It's - apparently - not part of the public API to do this. Perhaps you can try something like `[slider setValue:@(10) forKey:@"maximum"]` or `@"maximumValue"`, but even if this works, your app might get rejected by Apple for using private APIs.

Answer (score 1):

The [WKInterfaceSlider documentation from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceSlider_class/index.html) indicates that it is not possible to change the minimum and maximum values of a `WKInterfaceSlider` programmatically—these can only be set in Interface Builder.

However, functionally this does not matter, because a `WKInterfaceSlider` is a visual bar of colour that is filled with color as the user rolls the digital crown. Programatically, you read back the value of the slider, which is reported as a number that is between the minimum and maximum values, based on the proportion of the slider that is filled. However, the slider itself does not display a value to the end user.

Therefore, you can achieve something exactly analogous to changing the minimum and maximum values of the slider, simply by storing those values in properties and calculating offset and multiplier properties that you apply to the value returned from the slider.

1. Create a slider in Interface Builder, with a minimum value of 0 and a maximum value of 100. (These values could in fact be anything, but this is the most simple solution as the values can then be directly read as percentages.)
2. Create minimumValue and maximumValue properties in your WatchKit App Extension.
3. Calculate a multiplier value calculated as `(maximumValue - minimumValue)/100`.
4. When you read a value from the `WKInterfaceSlider`, simply calculate it as `(WKInterfaceSliderValue * multiplier) + minimumValue`.

At any time, you can change the minimumValue and maximumValue properties and you will get values in your new desired range from 4.

Note there is also a method to change the number of steps set programatically between the minimum and maximum values, using the method [`setNumberOfSteps(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceSlider_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfaceSlider/setNumberOfSteps:). This does not affect the calculation above but of course does affect the possible values that the slider will return to you within that range.